# How to just remove 0x0a but not 0x0d 0x0a?

Tags: command-line, one-liner

I want to remove the NL character but not the NL character after the CR character. `tr` would not do this. What is the best command to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Perl can do this:

```sh
$ od -c file
0000000   o   n   e  \n   t   w   o  \r  \n   t   h   r   e   e  \n   f
0000020   o   u   r  \r  \n  \n
0000026

$ perl -0777 -pe 's/(\A|[^\r])\n/$1/g' file > file.out

$ od -c file.out
0000000   o   n   e   t   w   o  \r  \n   t   h   r   e   e   f   o   u
0000020   r  \r  \n
0000023
```